# android Scrolling folder widgets

Tags: android

I am complete newbie to Android development and I have to make a Home screen app like this one

http://www.4shared.com/video/tjKMbnEk/noteBook.html

It must have the scrolling folder widgets , I am not much familiar with Android terminology and having a hard time searching for this stuff. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: see my answer below, but if you're completely new to Android, I suggest to also grab a book, i.e. Professional Android 2 Developer by Reto Meier is not bad. Or at least read about the terminology on developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to set your main activity as a default home activity. In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you set this for your main activity:

```
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

This will give the user the option to choose your app/activity as the home screen.

Comment: Look into Animations / Transitions. TranslateAnimation: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html and http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#tween-animation